# error When use JsonObjectRequest in my project

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I try to receive json from url
But there is a problem when you run the application

Error:(34, 83) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

```
 package mystore.com.example.hossam_aristo.mysqldbok;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

  import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView texv;

RequestQueue requestQueue;
String urlShowAllStudnet = "http://localhost/android/showAllStudent.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    texv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtV);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);





    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlShowAllStudnet,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("allstudent");
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){
                        JSONObject res = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = res.getString("id");
                        String name = res.getString("username");
                        String email = res.getString("email");
                        texv.append("\n " + id + name + email);

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
String id = res.getString("id");
```

to

```
String id = res.get("id").toString();
```

I think this will work!

Comment: The error indicates
Request.Method.GET
In particular
Method

Comment: Can you post the logcat or compilation error massage?

Comment: @HossamHany Try `String id = res.getInt("id").toString();`

Comment: Error:(50, 57) error: int cannot be dereferenced
Error:(40, 83) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.